# TestCafe --retry-test-pages behaviour for empty page

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm trying to understand the retry-test-pages feature for TC. Let's consider the case while I'm trying to run tests, but forgot to run frontend application (usually hosted at http://localhost:6666). Test runner creates new browser instance, redirects to the localhost:6666 but is unable to get the response.

**Current behaviour:**

- Quarantine mode - tries to reopen the page 3 times, throws an error.
- Retry-test-pages - throw an error on first attempt. There is no retries at all.

**Expected behaviour:**

- Shouldn't --retry-test-pages retry the request up to ten times before failed?

**Execution parameters:**

CLI: testcafe chrome ./features_tests/retry_test_pages --retry-test-pages --hostname localhost

Code:

```
import selectors from '../retryTestPages.po';

fixture("Retry Test Pages")
    .beforeEach(async t => {
        await t
            .navigateTo(http://localhost:6666)
            .expect(selectors.header.exists).ok({ timeout: 20000 });
    });

test
    ('Test 1', async t => {
        await t
            .click(selectors.nonExistingElement);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior. The [`--quarantine-mode`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/command-line-interface.html#-q---quarantine-mode) option restarts the whole test. As the same time, [`--retry-test-pages`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/command-line-interface.html#--retry-test-pages) retries sending requests on the Web browser side. So, a browser should know that the page exists and it can retry sending a request. Technically, that means that the [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FetchEvent) event should fire.